# Is there a way to view an object's variables without seeing all the base class stuff In Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

In particular, examining a Windows Form object, I want to see the members defined in my code without always seeing the hundreds of members defined by the framework in the base class.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using watcher?

Comment: The image is from Watch 1

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple inbuilt ways using Framework Attributes (though none of which particularly scalable).

---

#### 1. Using [`[DebuggerDisplay]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Assume your class looks like this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

you can [add the `[DebuggerDisplayAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2017) to the class like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Foo = {Foo}, Bar = {Bar}")
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

which now only shows `Foo` and `Bar`.

**Advantage:** displays only those members you wish to.

**Disadvantage:** you have to explicitly specify the members to display, and repeat that step for every property you add later.

---

#### 2. Using [`[DebuggerTypeProxy]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

You can define a proxy class that should be shown in the debugger instead of your real class.

Again, assuming that your class looks like this

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

you can now go ahead and define a proxy class that exposes only those members that you want to display and [apply the `[DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/x810d419(v=vs.85)) to the class like this:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(MyFormDebugView))]
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class MyFormDebugView
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Now you will only see `Foo` and `Bar` in the debugger display, not the inherited members of `Form`.

**Advantage:** displays only the members in the proxy class. No need to specify those members explicitly.

**Disadvantage:** you have to adjust the proxy type whenever you add a new property etc. to your `MyForm` that should be seen in the debugger.